# MIPS32 - Deallocate memory

Tags: memory, memory-management, mips

Suppose I have a linked list in MIPS32 and at some point I want to remove one of the nodes. 
What I do it to make the predecessor node to point to the next node of the node removed. 
However the removed node still contains some data. So the question is how do I find out whether that node is usable in future or not?

One suggestion was to create a second linked list containing all the nodes that are usable. However, how would I go to implement such a list? Also, do you think this list should point to all the usable space in memory or just to the one of the removed nodes?

Is there any other better way to accomplish the same result?

**Solution**:

Whenever we "ask" for new memory we use the sbrk service using syscall. However, if we've removed something from our data structure we may want to use that removed part of memory.

So a solution could be to have a linked list of nodes that could be re-used. Whenever we remove something from our data structure we add the part of memory (i.e. a node) to the linked list that keeps track of re-usable memory.

Therefore, when we've to add something to our data structure we first check whether there is some re-usable node in our "memory linked list". If this is not the case, we can use sbrk as usual.

Comment: Why do you want to remove usable nodes?

Comment: I did not say I want to remove them. I want the removed nodes to be usable again.

Comment: Oh, I must have misread. You just want a pool of reusable nodes. This is more of a data structure question then anything else. Can be achieved in verity of ways, even with a simple array. It really depends on what kind of properties you want it to have.

Comment: I see your point. Then should I just say: 1- if there are reusable nodes use those, otherwise call sbrk using syscall?

Comment: That's one way to approach it. One must consider the mount of memory wasted as well. If you keep allocating more memory, do you really want to always want to keep it all? Or do want to deallocate if a certain threshold is reached.

Comment: Actually I just read that using syscall everytime it's expensive, so a solution would be to request a big chunk of memory..but then I should also keep track of the free memory before the next syscall and this seems quite hard if the data structure is not linear (like a tree). Any idea?

Comment: Note that such things to be concerned with right off the bat usually qualify as premature optimization. It is expensive when used rapidity, however this is why you have a node pool to begin with - you start out with a pool of X nodes to begin with.

Comment: You should put the solution as an answer and accept it, not as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever we "ask" for new memory we use the sbrk service using syscall. However, if we've removed something from our data structure we may want to use that removed part of memory.

So a solution could be to have a linked list of nodes that could be re-used. Whenever we remove something from our data structure we add the part of memory (i.e. a node) to the linked list that keeps track of re-usable memory.

Therefore, when we've to add something to our data structure we first check whether there is some re-usable node in our "memory linked list". If this is not the case, we can use sbrk as usual.